# Threading - How to recieve and reply at the same time using the socket module?

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, while-loop, message

I am trying to make a simple LAN instant messager where many clients connect to the server and the server replies back and can see what the client is saying. I have tried but my lack of knowledge using the threading module has limited me. At the moment, however, the server only gets a message and has to reply to get the next one. I am trying to make it so the server can see all the messages it receives instantly and can reply whenever he need to. How?
Server Code:

```
from threading import *
import socket

s = socket.socket()         
host = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
port = 1337
s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(5)

def getMainThread():
    for thread in enumerate(): # Imported from threading
        if thread.name == 'MainThread':
            return thread
        if thread.name == 'Thread':
            return thread
    return None

class client(Thread):
    def __init__(self, socket, address):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.socket = socket
        self.address = address
        self.start() # Initated the thread, this calls run()

    def reply(self):
        reply = getThread()
        while reply and reply.isAlive():
            sent = input("Enter Message: ")
            self.socket.send(bytes(sent, 'UTF-8'))

    def run(self):
        main = getMainThread()
        while main and main.isAlive():
            message = self.socket.recv(8192).decode('utf-8')
            self.socket.send(b"Got your message.. send another one!")
            print('Someone:',message)
            sent = input("Enter Message: ")
            self.socket.send(bytes(sent, 'UTF-8'))



            self.socket.close()

    while True:
       c, addr = s.accept()
       client(c, addr)
```

Client Code:

```
import socket
host = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
print("""
================================================================================
Welcome to Coder77's local internet message for avoiding surveillance by the NSA
================================================================================
The current soon to be encrypted server is {0}
""".format(host))

#host = input("Please select the IP you would like to communicate to: ")
print("Now connecting to {0}....".format(host))

sock = socket.socket()
try:
    sock.connect((host, 1337))
    while True:
        message = input("Enter Message: ")
        if message == 'quit':
            break
        sock.send(bytes(message, 'UTF-8'))
        recieved = sock.recv(8192).decode('utf-8')
        print('Server responded with:', recieved)
except socket.error:
     print ("Host is unreachable")

sock.close()
```

Also, is it possible using Threading so that 2 while statements can run at the same time? If so, can someone give me an example?

Boosting this to try and get an answer. Anyone?

Comment: Should there be someone sitting on front of the server and chat or should the server distribute what a client says to all the other clients? Nice idea to build a chat server.. You may want to look at the `SocketServer` module.

Comment: There will be a physical person, yes. The reason both of the scripts say host is equal to localhost is because I am testing it on just my PC. But there will be a server on 192.168.1.0 and all the other clients will be on other PC's with different internal IP's.